# Can you call a function using different sized boost::multi_arrays?

Tags: c++, boost, boost-multi-array

I am trying to build a function to write multidimensional arrays to the file system. In order to keep it compact I would like to just create one function for different sized multi_arrays.

```
typedef boost::multi_array<int, 2> Array2D;
typedef boost::multi_array<int, 3> Array3D;
typedef boost::multi_array<int, 4> Array4D;
typedef boost::multi_array<int, 5> Array5D;

void writeArrayToFile(boost::multi_array_base_type array){
    // do things with array
}

void main(){
    Array2D myArray2D; // + fill array
    writeArrayToFile(myArray2D);

    Array3D myArray3D; // + fill array
    writeArrayToFile(myArray3D);
    //... and so on
}
```

is there such a thing as `boost::multi_array_base_type` or are there other ways to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Templates are your friends in c++. You solve problems with templates. Learn to love them:

```
template<std::size_t N>
void writeArrayToFile(const boost::multi_array<int, N>& array) {
    // do things with array
}
```

You can then call your function like that and let the compiler deduce the size:

```
writeArrayToFile(myArray2D);
writeArrayToFile(myArray3D);
```

If you like, you can even deduce the element type:

```
template<typename T, std::size_t N>
void writeArrayToFile(const boost::multi_array<T, N>& array) {
    // do things with array
}
```

Comment: Thanks! That's a great solution.

Comment: @coJetty consider upvoting then, and maybe accepting the answer if it fits your needs.